# Why sfc does not run in Windows PowerShell 7.2.7?

Tags: windows, powershell-7.0

PowerShell 7.2.7
sfc /verifyonly
Windows Resource Protection could not start the repair service.

No problem with running sfc under PowerShell 5 of from cmd.exe

Comment: Have you checked Event Viewer? Is this running as admin? What is the full command you are running? Where in the path are you when you run it? Is this part of a script, or just a single command you're typing in? What research have you done?

Comment: Also, this: https://superuser.com/questions/1265260/windows-sfc-scannow-windows-resource-protection-could-not-start-the-repair-se?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C132.2151

Answer (score 0):

Make sure PS architecture matches the OS architecture. You need PSx64 on Windows-x64.